# Transpose non square matrices C#

Tags: c#, matrix, multidimensional-array

I can transpose a square matrix, but now I'd like to transpose a non square matrix (in my code 3*2) with user input.

Other sources recommended me to create a new matrix first, which I have done. I manage to make the matrix, but when transposing, it stops from the 4th value.

I have looked at other topics but I can't find the error. Here is my code so far, can someone tell me where I went wrong?

Thanks!

```
        //const
        const int ROWS = 3;
        const int COLS = 2;

        //first matrix
        int[,] matrix1 = new int[ROWS, COLS];
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter num: ");
                matrix1[i, j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }

        //output
        Console.WriteLine("Eerste matrix: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(matrix1[i, j] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
        }

        //transposed matrix
        Console.WriteLine("Tweede matrix: ");
        int[,] matrix2 = new int[COLS, ROWS];
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            {
                matrix2[j, i] = matrix1[j, i];
                Console.Write(matrix2[j, i] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
        }
```

This is what I get when running the program:

```
        //output
        Enter num: 1
        Enter num: 2
        Enter num: 3
        Enter num: 4
        Enter num: 5
        Enter num: 6
        first matrix: 
        1 2  
        3 4  
        5 6  
        transposed matrix: 
        1 3  
        2 4  

        //--->> Only went up to 4th value?
```

Comment: You should be getting an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you combine the other two answers, you will have a complete picture:

This line is wrong and will give you an `IndexOutOfRangeException`:

```
matrix2[j, i] = matrix1[j, i];
```

In order to transpose you need to flip the indices:

```
matrix2[j, i] = matrix1[i, j];
```

Another problem is that when you print the matrix, you switch rows and columns.
It's easier to just extract the code for each functionality into a separate method.
Also, using the names i and j can be confusing. They look alike and they don't convey their meaning. When working with matrices, I like to use r and c (or row and column)

```
void PrintMatrix(int[,] m)
{
    int rows = m.GetLength(0);
    int columns = m.GetLength(1);
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
            Console.Write(m[r, c] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

int[,] TransposeMatrix(int[,] m)
{
    int rows = m.GetLength(0);
    int columns = m.GetLength(1);
    int[,] transposed = new int[columns, rows];
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
            transposed[c, r] = m[r, c];
        }
    }
    return transposed;
}
```

Then the last part of your code becomes simply:

```
PrintMatrix(matrix1);
Console.WriteLine();
int[,] matrix2 = TransposeMatrix(matrix1);
PrintMatrix(matrix2);
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the job! But does't that print the matrix in 2*3 instead of 3*2? Because I would like to print it out in 3 * 2.

Comment: It will print the matrix row by row. If the matrix has 2 rows, it will print 2 rows. If it has 3 rows it will print 3 rows. That's usually how we print a matrix.

Answer (score 3):

So, at the beginning you load a matrix with fields : "i,j" => "row, column"

On the last step, you try accessing the matrix with a "j,i" => "column, row" order.

You're inverting the i,j indexes.-

Let me help you by just changing the variable names :

//const

```
    const int ROWS = 3;
    const int COLS = 2;

    //first matrix
    int[,] matrix1 = new int[ROWS, COLS];
    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < COLS; column ++)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter num: ");
            matrix1[row, column] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }
```

//output

```
    Console.WriteLine("Eerste matrix: ");
    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < COLS; column++)
        {`enter code here`
            Console.Write(matrix1[row, column] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
    }
```

//transposed matrix

```
    Console.WriteLine("Tweede matrix: ");
    int[,] matrix2 = new int[COLS, ROWS];
    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < COLS; column++)
        {
            matrix2[column, row] = matrix1[row, column];
            Console.Write(matrix2[column, row] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
    }
```

// EDIT : actually noticed the sample didn't traspose it properly. fixed it.

Comment: Thank you. I will pay attention to that.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
 matrix2[j, i] = matrix1[j, i];
```

with

```
 matrix2[j, i] = matrix1[i, j];
```

This way a row number of matrix1 becomes a column number for matrix2 - i.e. the matrix gets transposed.